# Programatic access to Home button in React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native, home-button

I'm trying to programatically call Home button with another button inside my project. App compiles fine, but when I tap the button that should call Home I receive following error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a
>   null object reference

Here is my code (just essentials):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.content.Context;

public class ClassName extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private Context context;

  @ReactMethod
  public void minApp() {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(startMain);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION:**

Due to the fact that my app uses react native, the code in bridged method in java file should look as below:

```
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.content.Context;

public class ClassName extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  @ReactMethod
  public void minApp() {
    Context context = getReactApplicationContext();
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(startMain);
  }
}
```

Using this we can assign `Home button` function anywhere we want ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void openLauncher(Context context) {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(startMain);
}
```

You can just open the launcher using this function.

Comment: This time I got following error: `Got unknown argument class: Context`

Comment: you haven't initialized the context variable, you should initialize it and set to the current Activity context or you can use `getContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` to be passed into the openLauncher method.

Comment: I updated my question and now the code looks as above. App compiles but when I call `minApp()` it throws an error: `Got unknown argument class: Context`.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you haven't initialized `context`. Make  sure to initiate it before calling `minApp()`